# Переменные и методы внутри потока не реагируют

Tags: java, многопоточность

Книга Я.Файн "Программирование Java для дедушек" глава 11 (213 стр.). Игра пинг-понг. Код скопирован из книги. В методе run() булев не меняется и методы не запускаются(мячик не двигается). Я понимаю, что переменные менялись после запуска потока. Как их передать или в чем проблема?

```
package engine;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import screens.*;
/**
 *Этот класс – обработчик событий мыши и клавиатуры.
 * Рассчитывает движение мяча и ракеток,изменение их координат.
 */
public class PingPongGameEngine implements Runnable,
    MouseMotionListener, KeyListener, GameConstants{
private PingPongGreenTable table; // ссылка на стол
private int kidRacket_Y = KID_RACKET_Y_START;
private int computerRacket_Y=COMPUTER_RACKET_Y_START;
private int kidScore;
private int computerScore;
private int ballX; // координата X мяча
private int ballY; // координата Y мяча
private boolean movingLeft = true;
private boolean ballServed = false;
 //   Программирование на Java для детей, родителей, бабушек и дедушек 212
//Значение вертикального передвижения мяча в пикселях
private int verticalSlide;
// Конструктор. Содержит ссылку на объект стола
public PingPongGameEngine(PingPongGreenTable greenTable){
    table = greenTable;
    Thread worker = new Thread(this);
    worker.start();
}
// Обязательные методы из интерфейса MouseMotionListener
// (некоторые из них пустые,но должны быть включены все равно)
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
}
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    int mouse_Y = e.getY();
// Если мышь находится выше ракетки ребенка
// и не выходит за пределы стола – передвинуть ее вверх,
// в противном случае – опустить вниз
    if (mouse_Y<kidRacket_Y && kidRacket_Y>TABLE_TOP){
        kidRacket_Y -= RACKET_INCREMENT;
    }else if (kidRacket_Y < TABLE_BOTTOM) {
        kidRacket_Y += RACKET_INCREMENT;
    }
    // Установить новое положение ракетки
    table.setKidRacket_Y(kidRacket_Y);
}
// Обязательные методы из интерфейса KeyListener
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    char key = e.getKeyChar();
    if ('n' == key || 'N' == key){
        startNewGame();
    } else if ('q' == key || 'Q' == key){
        endGame();
    } else if ('s' == key || 'S' == key){
        kidServe();
    }
//Программирование на Java для детей, родителей, бабушек и дедушек 213
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
// Начать новую игру
public void startNewGame(){
    computerScore=0;
    kidScore=0;
    table.setMessageText("Score Computer: 0 Kid: 0");
    kidServe();
}
// Завершить игру
public void endGame(){
    System.exit(0);
}
// Обязательный метод run() из интерфейса Runnable
public void run(){
    boolean canBounce=false;
    while (true) {
        if(ballServed){ // если мяч движется!!!!
            //Шаг 1. Мяч движется влево?
            if ( movingLeft && ballX > BALL_MIN_X){
                canBounce = (ballY >= computerRacket_Y &&
                        ballY < (computerRacket_Y + RACKET_LENGTH)?true: false);
                ballX-=BALL_INCREMENT;
                // Добавить смещение вверх или вниз к любым
                // движениям мяча влево или вправо
                ballY-=verticalSlide;
                table.setBallPosition(ballX,ballY);
                // Может отскочить?
                if (ballX <= COMPUTER_RACKET_X && canBounce){
                    movingLeft=false;
                }
            }
            // Шаг 2. Мяч движется вправо?
            if ( !movingLeft && ballX <= BALL_MAX_X){
                canBounce = (ballY >= kidRacket_Y && ballY <
                        (kidRacket_Y + RACKET_LENGTH)?true:false);
                ballX+=BALL_INCREMENT;
                table.setBallPosition(ballX,ballY);
// Может отскочить?
                if (ballX >= KID_RACKET_X && canBounce){
                    movingLeft=true;
                }
            }
            // Шаг 3. Перемещать ракетку компьютера вверх или вниз,
            // чтобы блокировать мяч
            if (computerRacket_Y < ballY
                    && computerRacket_Y < TABLE_BOTTOM){
                computerRacket_Y +=RACKET_INCREMENT;
            }else if (computerRacket_Y > TABLE_TOP){
                computerRacket_Y -=RACKET_INCREMENT;
            }
            table.setComputerRacket_Y(computerRacket_Y);
            // Шаг 4. Приостановить
            try {
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Шаг 5. Обновить счет, если мячв зеленой области, но не движется
            if (isBallOnTheTable()){
                if (ballX > BALL_MAX_X ){
                    computerScore++;
                    displayScore();
                }else if (ballX < BALL_MIN_X){
                    kidScore++;
                    displayScore();
                }
            }
        } // Конец if ballServed
    } // Конец while
}// Конец run()
//Программирование на Java для детей, родителей, бабушек и дедушек 215
// Подать с текущей позиции ракетки ребенка
private void kidServe(){
    ballServed = true;
    ballX = KID_RACKET_X-1;
    ballY=kidRacket_Y;
    if (ballY > TABLE_HEIGHT/2){
        verticalSlide=-1;
    }else{
        verticalSlide=1;
    }
    table.setBallPosition(ballX,ballY);
    table.setKidRacket_Y(kidRacket_Y);
}
private void displayScore(){
    ballServed = false;
    if (computerScore ==WINNING_SCORE){
        table.setMessageText("Computer won! " + computerScore +
                ":" + kidScore);
    }else if (kidScore ==WINNING_SCORE){
        table.setMessageText("You won! "+ kidScore +
                ":" + computerScore);
    }else{
        table.setMessageText("Computer: "+ computerScore +
                " Kid: " + kidScore);
    }
}
// Проверить, не пересек ли мяч верхнюю или нижнюю границу стола
private boolean isBallOnTheTable(){
    if (ballY >= BALL_MIN_Y && ballY <= BALL_MAX_Y){
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Вдумчиво читать про JMM и волатильность.

Comment: почитал, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

добавить модификатор "volatile" переменной "ballserved"